# Where are the pre-beta questions

Tags: discussion

Way back before the site went beta, I submitted a few questions (that I actually knew the answer to.)  I was thinking about submitting them to the site now that it's in full operation but I don't remember what they were.

Were they saved somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

You can still get all of the information from the pre-beta phases from Area51. When you click on the Woodworking page, there are three tabs in the top-right corresponding to the definition, commitment, and beta pages:

[image]

You can click on the [definition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61927?phase=definition) tab to see 
all of the questions that were proposed in the definition phase.